# match formula when first cell in search range is empty?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

is it possible to use an empty cell in a match formula?

I have a value in my cell A3. I want to search this value using 'match' in a matrix A4:A13 (or any other matrix). However, in this case, cell A4 is empty (I cannot help it, it is the way figures are returned from another program). 
To be able to search in this matrix I thought I could substitute the value in A3 with {empty}.
substituting works. But then, the Match formula does not work.

The actual formula then would be:

`=match("";A4:A13;0)`

I cannot change the empty cell in my search range. That one is given. Is there something else I can do to make this work?

**edit:**

this is the objective of my document:
I have a dashboard sheet on which figures presented.
on this sheet, in column A there are first: account name, brand 1, brand 2, brand 3, brand 4, brand 5 (if applicable,), A.VOGEL, OTHER (result of account total minus the sum of all the brands).

So in this case, cells A3:A10. The figures come from a different sheet. This output is like:

`a1 = account name (other cells in this row are empty
a2 = empty, b2 contains a value that cannot be used, c2 shows the brand name (and because in this case, it represents the account total and no brand, c2 is empty) and from D2 : L2, there are values, corresponding to the given value in a1.
a3 = empty, b3 contains a value that cannot be used, c3 has the name of the brand and again, in D3: L3 there are the values.`

See my example below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv8wvhtw0aa54dd/output%20sheet%201.png

and the dashboard sheet:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgt7omkcytm7xef/DASHBOARD%20sheet%201.png

(and after this account 'nl food-drug' many other account will follow with the same structure).

given this structure, I am trying to create a formula which I can easily paste in every row in the dashboard sheet without being concerned my search matrix will be incorrect. 
I thought I was able to do this, but I got stuck.

I would like to have only one formula, which contains everything to have the complete search matrix for both the account total and the individual brands, but which also adjusts and refers to the right account. (so adjusts cell references correctly).

I had 2 different formulas which work: 1 for the account total and 1 for the brands. But I am sure there will be a mistake sometime when I copy paste these rows down the sheet.
My formula always refers to the cell where the account name is in. In the example: A3. To always refer to the right cell I was trying the address, match, indirect formula's together. 
one formula which is working now:

`=ALS(ISFOUT(INDEX(INDIRECT(ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+2;4;1;1;"NIELSEN FD-omzet")&":"&ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+6;12;1;1;);WAAR);VERGELIJKEN($A4;INDIRECT(ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+2;3;1;1;"NIELSEN FD-OMZET")&":"&ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+7;3;1;1;));0);VERGELIJKEN(B$2;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$D$2:$L$2;0)));"";INDEX(INDIRECT(ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+2;4;1;1;"NIELSEN FD-omzet")&":"&ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+6;12;1;1;);WAAR);VERGELIJKEN($A4;INDIRECT(ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+2;3;1;1;"NIELSEN FD-OMZET")&":"&ADRES(VERGELIJKEN($A$3;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$A:$A;0)+7;3;1;1;));0);VERGELIJKEN(B$2;'NIELSEN FD-omzet'!$D$2:$L$2;0)))`

nice formula, right? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(A4:A13),0),0)
```

Comment: Then change the range to A5:A13

Comment: Not if you ignore that cell to find another blank.

Comment: the range is unknown. I am searching for a way to determine the range and therefore, I need this formula to determine the row number of the range. However, my current formula has become so awfully complicated that I do not understand it anymore myself.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, we have stumbled across an anomaly that provides a very simple solution.  Try the following:

```
=XMATCH(,A1:A3)
```

In this example, we have omitted the first argument which technically isn't optional (the anomaly). Interestingly, the match argument appears to process this value as a blank cell and returns its position.  As in the original message above, we first assumed that a double-quote ("") would represent a blank cell but, when it didn't, we eventually found this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Say **B1:B4** is the table of values an **A1** is the value to find.

This formula:

```
=IF(A1="",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B1:B4="",0),0),MATCH(A1,B1:B5,0))
```

will work where **A1** is empty or not!  For example:

[image: first]

and for empty:

[image: second]

**EDIT#1**

For the Poster's case this would be:

```
=IF(A3="",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A4:A13="",0),0),MATCH(A3,A4:A13,0))
```

or just:
    =MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A4:A13=A3,0),0)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will try! one other thing: is it possible that I am trying to create an endless formula because I am always using the match formula to create a search matrix, but because the match formula consists of a search matrix, it keeps on going and going. is that true?

Comment: For every search matrix in the match formula, i am adding a new match formula. This way, my formula never ends.